# How to check and exclude items in SQL based on values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a database where I need to get a list of users who were not able to log into our service. We have rows that contain an ID (uID) and an auth_field that either gives us 'true' or 'false' based on if the user is able to login.

| uID | auth_field |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 'false' |
| 8788 | 'false' |
| 1234 | **'true'** |
| 8788 | 'false' |
| 1234 | **'true'** |
| 8788 | 'false' |
| 6666 | 'false' |

Based on the above output, 1234 was able to login so I want to exclude every result containing that uID from my query including the 'false' field.

```
SELECT uID, COUNT(uID)
FROM database
GROUP BY uID
HAVING (auth_field) ='false'
```

This gets me a list of users that auth failed, but I need to exclude duplicates that have auth_field = 'true'

I'm somewhat at a loss on how to give back a return that excludes every uID if there is one 'true' auth_field.

My thinking is to have the below somewhere in here but can't make it work
'WHERE NOT auth_field = 'true'

Comment: What is `HAVING (auth_field) ='false'` meant to do? I'd expect an aggregation function in the HAVING clause.

Comment: Several ways to do this. One is using `except`, such as `select uid from table where auth_field = 'false' except select uid from table where auth_field = 'true'`. The _except_ clause will automatically de-dupe the users, too.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result. (I.e. provide a complete [mcve].)'

Comment: "This gets me a list of users that auth failed" - It shouldn't. Your query is invalid. You group by user ID, but in your `HAVING` clause you check the `auth_field`. Which one? There are several rows per user ID, so there is no single `auth_field` that you can check. The query must result in an error, but you say it doesn't? I know this behavior from MySQL run in a cheat mode that allows such invalid queries and just returns arbitrary results. Other DBMDS should raise an error.

Comment: You can change `HAVING (auth_field) ='false'` to `HAVING MAX(auth_field) ='false'`. This is because `auth_field` seems to be a string, and 'true'  comes after 'false' in the alphabet. So if the maximum auth_field for a user ID is 'false', then all its auth_fields are 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```sql
SELECT uId
FROM database
GROUP BY uId
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN auth_field = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Or in simpler form:

```sql
SELECT uId
FROM database
GROUP BY uId
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(IF(auth_field = 'false', 1, 0));
```

Also, this works too:

```sql
SELECT uId
FROM database
GROUP BY uId
HAVING SUM(auth_field = 'true') = 0;
```

For example, the output for your data is as follows:

```
8788
6666
```

**Note:** if your data type is **Boolean**, use `false`, otherwise `'false'`

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
SELECT 
    uID, listagg(distinct auth_field) within group (order by auth_field) as auth
FROM database
GROUP BY 1
)
select 
   uId
from cte 
   where auth = 'false'
```

Answer (score 0):

If every log in attempt failed, you'd have **'false'** for both `min` and `max` **auth_field** per **uId**. So you can modify your code to..

```
select uID, count(uID)
from  database
group by uID
having min(auth_field) = 'false' and max(auth_field) = 'false'
```

Alternatively, if **auth_field** isn't already a `boolean`, you can convert to `boolean`, then `int`, then require a `sum = 0`

```
select uID, count(uID)
from  database
group by uID
having sum(auth_field::boolean::int) = 0
```

Comment: You can remove `min(auth_field) = 'false' and`. It suffices that the maximum auth_field is 'false', because then there can be no 'true' for the user ID.

Comment: Correct but having both min and max in there makes it more self-explanatory rather than relying on alphabetical order of f<t